# Caching in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

A function is defined to transform an RDD. Therefore, the function is called once for each element in the RDD.

The function needs to call an external web service to look up reference data, passing as a parameter data from the current element in the RDD.

Two questions:

1. Is there an issue with issuing a web service call within Spark?
2. The data from the web service needs to be cached. What is the best way to hold (and subsequently reference) the cached data? The simple way would be to hold the cache in a collection with the Scala class which contains the function being passed to the RDD. Would this be efficient, or is there a better approach for caching in Spark?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There isn't really any mechanism for "caching" (in the sense that you mean). Seems like the best approach would be to split this task into two phases:

1. Get the *distinct* "keys" by which you must access the external lookup, and perform the lookup once for each key
2. Use this mapping to perform the lookup for each record in the RDD

I'm assuming there would potentially be **many records accessing the same lookup key** (otherwise "caching" won't be of any value anyway), so performing the external calls for the *distinct* keys is substantially faster.

**How should you implement this**?

- **If** you know this set of distinct keys is **small enough** to fit into your driver machine's memory:

  - map your data into the distinct **keys** by which you'd want to cache these fetched values, and collect it, e.g. : `val keys = inputRdd.map(/* get key */).distinct().collect()`
  - perform the fetching on driver-side (not using Spark)
  - use the resulting `Map[Key, FetchedValues]` in any transformation on your original RDD - it will be serialized and sent to each worker where you can perform the lookup. For example, assuming the input has records for which the `foreignId` field is the lookup key:

    ```
    val keys = inputRdd.map(record => record.foreignId).distinct().collect()
    val lookupTable = keys.map(k => (k, fetchValue(k))).asMap
    val withValues = inputRdd.map(record => (record, lookupTable(record.foreignId)))
    ```
  - Alternatively - if this map is large (but still can fit in driver memory), you can **broadcast** it before you use it in RDD transformation - see [Broadcast Variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) in Spark's Programming Guide
- **Otherwise** (if this map might be too large) - you'll need to use `join` if you want keep data in the cluster, but to still refrain from fetching the same element twice:

  ```
  val byKeyRdd = inputRdd.keyBy(record => record.foreignId)
  val lookupTableRdd = byKeyRdd
    .keys()
    .distinct()
    .map(k => (k, fetchValue(k))) // this time fetchValue is done in cluster - concurrently for different values
  val withValues = byKeyRdd.join(lookupTableRdd)
  ```

Comment: Thanks Tzach. Presumably the best place to hold the cache (driver side) would be in a scala object. To clarify, are you saying that if the cache is large, prefer a broadcast variable because otherwise there would be a performance overhead in sending the cache to each transformation mapping function? Note that the cache will not be static, but will grow with the processing of different requests (each request will be processed as a separate RDD). Would the the broadcast variable still be a better approach (for a large cache) despite the overhead of constantly updating the broadcast variable?

Comment: Oh - I see. Yes, broadcast is only better because it gives you control of when the variable is sent - if you have to re-send it over and over anyway, then it probably wouldn't be of much value.

Comment: Do you think the overhead of sending a potentially large cache to the RDD could be an issue? It would likely only be sent once for the processing of each RDD.

Comment: It could - depending on its size, and on your expectation... e.g. if your jobs takes 30 minutes, this serialization would probably be negligible. If it takes 40 seconds, then by comparison this might be significant.

Comment: With the second answer Tzach (data stored on the cluster) - would that allow for one global cache which all nodes would be writing to and reading from ?

Comment: Not really - all nodes would hold partitions of that "cache", which won't behave like a cache at all, but like an RDD that you create _once_ and then _join_ however many times you want. So if an item from this cache is needed by a record in another node, that would involve a shuffle operation.

Comment: would that shuffle happen automatically?

Comment: of course. It's a join, read more about Spark joins [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shuffle-operations)