# How does Spark's StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD work?

Tags: apache-spark, linear-regression, apache-spark-mllib

I am working on [`StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearRegressionWithSGD.html) which has two methods [`trainOn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.html#trainOn(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)) and [`predictOn`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.html#predictOn(org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream)). This class has a [model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.html#latestModel()) object that is updated as training data arrives in the stream specified in `trainOn` argument.

Simultaneously It give prediction using same model.

I want to know that how the model weights are updated and synchronized across workers/executors.

Any link or reference will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magic here. `StreamingLinearAlgorithm` [keeps a mutable reference](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a1e40b1f5d651305bbd0ba05779263a44f607498/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala#L65) to the current `GeneralizedLinearModel`.

`trainOn` [uses `DStream.foreachRDD` to train a new model on each batch, and then updates the `model`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a1e40b1f5d651305bbd0ba05779263a44f607498/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala#L92-L94). Similarly [`predictOn` uses `DStream.map` to predict](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a1e40b1f5d651305bbd0ba05779263a44f607498/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/StreamingLinearAlgorithm.scala#L123) with the current version of the `model`.

Since Spark will serialize closures for each stage there is no need for any additional synchronization. Spark will use the current value of the `model` each time it computes the closure.

Effectively it equivalent to running a loop on the driver with interleaving `run` and `predict`.

Comment: Thank u for answer, I dug up the code and found that in GradientDescent weights are being broadcasted. Is this the step where synchronization of weights happen. Each executor may compute different weight locally what is happening in that case.