# how to create a global variable in spark that can be used across all nodes

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need to use a variable across all nodes in spark yarn cluster.
Broadcast variables in spark are immutable so, not useful in my case.
I need a similar approach that supports both read and write.

Regards,
Sorabh

Answer (score 3):

You cannot, Spark is built on the principle of immutability, in fact any distributed framework works by leveraging the concepts of immutability.

Here is a similar question and beautiful explanation : 
[How to define a global read\write variables in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401537/how-to-define-a-global-read-write-variables-in-spark)

Comment: Not really,  there are accumulators

Comment: quoting from https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#accumulators "Accumulators are variables that are only “added” Tasks running on a cluster can then add to it using the add method. However, they cannot read its value "

Comment: Yes, but it means that not everything is immutable ;)

Comment: Thanks, but whats the solution. If i use broadcast variable then its readonly, and accumulators will also not serve my purpose. I need to share a VO that can be updated by all the worker nodes.