# Set column value depending on previous ones with Spark without repeating grouping attribute

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Given the DataFrame:

```
+------------+---------+
|variableName|dataValue|
+------------+---------+
|       IDKey|       I1|
|           b|        y|
|           a|        x|
|       IDKey|       I2|
|           a|        z|
|           b|        w|
|           c|        q|
+------------+---------+
```

I want to create a new column with corresponding IDKey values, where each value changes whenever the dataValue for IDKey changes, here's the expected output :

```
+------------+---------+----------+
|variableName|dataValue|idkeyValue|
+------------+---------+----------+
|       IDKey|       I1|        I1|
|           b|        y|        I1|
|           a|        x|        I1|
|       IDKey|       I2|        I2|
|           a|        z|        I2|
|           b|        w|        I2|
|           c|        q|        I2|
+------------+---------+----------+
```

I tried by doing the following code which uses `mapPartitions()` and a global variable

```
var currentVarValue = ""
frame
  .mapPartitions{ partition =>
    partition.map { row =>
      val (varName, dataValue) = (row.getString(0), row.getString(1))

      val idKeyValue = if (currentVarValue != dataValue && varName == "IDKey") {
        currentVarValue = dataValue
        dataValue
      } else {
        currentVarValue
      }

      ExtendedData(varName, dataValue, currentVarValue)
    }
  }
```

But this won't work because of two fundamental things: [Spark doesn't handle global variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401537/how-to-define-a-global-read-write-variables-in-spark) and also, this doesn't comply with functional programming style

I will gladly appreciate any help on this. Thanks!

Comment: Could you give more details about the rule that makes idkeyValue changes please ? If I understand, whenever the tuple (variableName, dataValue) changes, idkeyValue changes right ?

Comment: I added some details, let me know if it's enough

Comment: I tried to compile your code, but I have this error `Error:(32, 22) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset....`, could you give us complete code please ?

Comment: If your dataset has a column for partitioning (e.g. by variable type or group), or if it's not large, using Window function would be pretty straight forward.

Comment: But it could be quite large or not?

Comment: So `idkeyValue` will be updated based on the order that it appears on the DF? If so, Not sure if that can be achieved by spark in a "safe" way. Based on `.map` will be executed in a distributed way and not sequentially, so having a reference in the "previous" item I don't think that it work. If you have a reference column that you can use to group them or even a row_count in the df.

Comment: This type of data feed is an example where initial parallel processing a la Spark does not shine. Not even sure how Spark can really optimize not knowing a major key / hashing key up-front. The initial computation is hard on time, the rest not. LeoC - our esteemed SF Scala person, alludes to that.

Comment: Can I state that the fact that there is not a solution is also an answer.

Comment: So, did u solve?

Answer (score 0):

> You cannot solve this **elegantly and performant** in a Spark way as
>   there is not enough initial information provided for Spark to process
>   all data guaranteed to be in the same partition. If we do all
>   processing in the same partition, then this is not the true intent of
>   Spark.

In fact a sensible partitionBy cannot be issued (over Window function). The issue here is that the data represents a *long list of sequential such data* that would require looking across partitions for if data in the previous partition relates to the current partition. That could be done, but it's quite a job. zero323 has an answer somewhere here that tries to solve this, but if I remember correctly, it is cumbersome.

The logic to do it is easy enough, but using Spark is problematic for this.

Without a partitionBy data all gets shuffled to a single partition and could result in OOM and space problems.

Sorry.